# Menu in Arduino is not change back when I reached the end and try go back

Tags: arduino

This is the code from someone for a water pump, I changed it to make a basic menu with the help of a YouTube video. Everything works fine, a lot fine, however, there is one problem.

To explain my problem, for example, when opening there is no problem, menu will be like

```
-Menu1
 Menu2
```

and when I press once to down, menu will be

```
 Menu1
-Menu2
```

Down again

```
 Menu2
-Menu3
```

Until here everything is fine, when I click the up button it works well and go back like

```
-Menu2
 Menu3
```

Then

```
-Menu1
 Menu2
```

However if I press down at Menu3 and go for Menu4, I cannot go up again, I mean I can but Menu names not change, it always Menu3 and Menu 4, functions are work for 1 and 2 when I click but the menu always be like

```
 Menu3
-Menu4
```

So that's the my problem, the code is below, so if you can help me, I would be really happy. This is my 1st week on my new work so I don't wanna be screw up :(

```
String menuItems[] = {"Menu1", "Menu2", "Menu3", "Menu4"};

// Navigation button variables
int readKey;
int button;

// Main Menu control variables:
int menuPage = 0;
int maxMenuPages = round(((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) / 2) + .2);
int cursorPosition = 0;

int a;
int b;


// Creates 3 custom characters for the menu display
byte downArrow[8] = {
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b10101, // * * *
  0b01110, //  ***
  0b00100  //   *
};

byte upArrow[8] = {
  0b00100, //   *
  0b01110, //  ***
  0b10101, // * * *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100, //   *
  0b00100  //   *
};

byte menuCursor[8] = {
  B01000, //  *
  B00100, //   *
  B00010, //    *
  B00001, //     *
  B00010, //    *
  B00100, //   *
  B01000, //  *
  B00000  //
};

#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// Setting the LCD shields pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup() {

  // Initializes serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initializes and clears the LCD screen
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();

  // Creates the byte for the 3 custom characters
  lcd.createChar(0, menuCursor);
  lcd.createChar(1, upArrow);
  lcd.createChar(2, downArrow);

}
    
void loop() {

  mainMenuDraw();
  drawCursor();
  operateMainMenu();

}
   

// This function,  for the MAIN menu, will generate the 2 menu items that can fit on the screen. 
//They will change as you scroll through your menu. 
//Up and down arrows will indicate your current menu position.
void mainMenuDraw() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
  lcd.print(menuItems[menuPage]);
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print(menuItems[menuPage + 1]);

  UpDnArrowDraw(menuPage, maxMenuPages);
  
}

void drawCursor() {
  for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, x);
    lcd.print(" ");
  }

  if (menuPage % 2 == 0) {
    if (cursorPosition % 2 == 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
    if (cursorPosition % 2 != 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
  }

  if (menuPage % 2 != 0) {
    if (cursorPosition % 2 == 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
    if (cursorPosition % 2 != 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
  }  
}

void operateMainMenu() {
  int activeButton = 0;
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    int button; 
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    
    if (readKey > 790) {  // Wait here if no buttons pushed; read value should be max (~1023)
    delay(50);
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    }    
    
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 0: // NO button returns as 0 there is no action taken
        break;
      case 1:
        button = 0;
        switch (cursorPosition) { 
          case 0:
            menuItem1();
            break;
          case 1:
            menuItem2();
            break;
          case 2:
            menuItem3();
            break;
          case 3:
            menuItem4();
            break;
              
        }

        activeButton = 1;
        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        break;

      case 2:
        button = 0;
        if (menuPage == 0) {
          cursorPosition = cursorPosition - 1;
          cursorPosition = constrain(cursorPosition, 0, ((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) - 1));
        }
        if (menuPage % 2 != 0 and cursorPosition % 2 == 0) {
          menuPage = menuPage - 1;
          menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);
        }
        if (menuPage % 2 != 0 and cursorPosition % 2 != 0) {
          menuPage = menuPage - 1;
          menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);
        }

        cursorPosition = cursorPosition - 1;
        cursorPosition = constrain(cursorPosition, 0, ((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) - 1));

        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        activeButton = 1;
        break;

       case 3:
         button = 0;
         if (menuPage % 2 == 0 and cursorPosition % 2 != 0) {
           menuPage = menuPage + 1;
           menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);
         }
         if (menuPage % 2 != 0 and cursorPosition % 2 == 0) {
           menuPage = menuPage + 1;
           menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);
         }

        cursorPosition = cursorPosition + 1;
        cursorPosition = constrain(cursorPosition, 0, ((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) - 1));

        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        activeButton = 1;
        break;

    }    
  }
}

// This function is called whenever a button is pressed and determines which of the 5 buttons was pressed, 
//based on the voltage drop across the buttons all hooked up to A0.
int evaluateButton(int x) {
  int result = 0; 
  x = analogRead(0);
  if (x < 800) {
    delay(100);
    x = analogRead(0);  // Performs glitch filtering
  }
  if (x < 50) {
    result = 1; // right button
  } else if (x < 200) {
    result = 2; // up button
  } else if (x < 400) {
    result = 3; // down button
  } else if (x < 600) {
    result = 4; // Left button
  } else if (x < 800) {
    result = 5; // Select button
  }
  return result;
}


void menuItem1() { // Function executes when you select the 1st item from main menu
  int activeButton = 0;
  
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("SubMenu1");
  
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    int button;                 // Debounce
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    while (readKey > 790) {  // Wait here if no buttons pushed; read value should be max (~1023)
      delay(10);
      readKey = analogRead(0);
    }    
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 4:  // This case will execute if the "back" button (e.g. LEFT) is pressed to go back to the Main menu
        button = 0;
        activeButton = 1;
        break;

    }
  }
}

void menuItem2() { // Function executes when you select the 1st item from main menu
  int activeButton = 0;
  
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("SubMenu2");
  
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    int button;                 // Debounce
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    while (readKey > 790) {  // Wait here if no buttons pushed; read value should be max (~1023)
      delay(10);
      readKey = analogRead(0);
    }    
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 4:  // This case will execute if the "back" button (e.g. LEFT) is pressed to go back to the Main menu
        button = 0;
        activeButton = 1;
        break;

    }
  }
}

void menuItem3()  { // Function executes when you select the 1st item from main menu
  int activeButton = 0;
  
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("SubMenu3");
  
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    int button;                 // Debounce
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    while (readKey > 790) {  // Wait here if no buttons pushed; read value should be max (~1023)
      delay(10);
      readKey = analogRead(0);
    }    
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 4:  // This case will execute if the "back" button (e.g. LEFT) is pressed to go back to the Main menu
        button = 0;
        activeButton = 1;
        break;

    }
  }
}

void menuItem4() { // Function executes when you select the 1st item from main menu
  int activeButton = 0;
  
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("lak lak lak");
  
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    int button;                 // Debounce
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    while (readKey > 790) {  // Wait here if no buttons pushed; read value should be max (~1023)
      delay(10);
      readKey = analogRead(0);
    }    
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 4:  // This case will execute if the "back" button (e.g. LEFT) is pressed to go back to the Main menu
        button = 0;
        activeButton = 1;
        break;

    }
  }
}



// This function will generate the arrows that indicate which UP/DN buttons to press.  

   int UpDnArrowDraw(int a,int b) {
  if (a == 0) {   // IF for Up/Dn arrows
    lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
    lcd.write(byte(2));  // Display DN arrow only ( BYTE 1 is UP arrow; BYTE 2 is DN arrow)
    lcd.setCursor(15, 0);
    lcd.print(" ");
      }
    else if (a > 0 and a < b ) {
    lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
    lcd.write(byte(2));
    lcd.setCursor(15, 0);
    lcd.write(byte(1));    // Display both UP and DN arrow
     }
    else if (a == b) {
    lcd.setCursor(15, 0);
    lcd.write(byte(1));   // Display UP arrow only
    lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
    lcd.print(" ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, changing the operateMainMenu part to this, miraculously solved everything lol, I'm gonna post it for who will use this code in future and dealing with this problem

```
void operateMainMenu() {
  int activeButton = 0;
  while (activeButton == 0) {
    int button; 
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    
    if (readKey > 790) {  // Wait here if no buttons pushed; read value should be max (~1023)
    delay(50);
    readKey = analogRead(0);
    }    
    
    button = evaluateButton(readKey);
    switch (button) {
      case 0: // NO button returns as 0 there is no action taken
        break;
      case 1:
        button = 0;
        switch (cursorPosition) { 
          case 0:
            menuItem1();
            break;
          case 1:
            menuItem2();
            break;
          case 2:
            menuItem3();
            break;
          case 3:
            menuItem4();
            break;
              
        }

        activeButton = 1;
        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        break;

      case 2:
        button = 0;
        cursorPosition = cursorPosition - 1;
        cursorPosition = constrain(cursorPosition, 0, ((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) - 1));
          menuPage = menuPage - 1;
          menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);

        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        activeButton = 1;
        break;

       case 3:
         button = 0;
         cursorPosition = cursorPosition + 1;
         cursorPosition = constrain(cursorPosition, 0, ((sizeof(menuItems) / sizeof(String)) - 1));
           menuPage = menuPage + 1;
           menuPage = constrain(menuPage, 0, maxMenuPages);

        mainMenuDraw();
        drawCursor();
        activeButton = 1;
        break;

    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: You might explain or indicate what has changed.  To describe it as "miraculous" rather suggests that you do not understand why it now works. In which case there is still perhaps a question to be answered perhaps.

Comment: I changed the cases which make me able to go up or down through the menu. I watched some "State Machine" videos and bam, it showed there is a mistake in cases in my code. The cases itself already work like "if" in my case, so when I put extra conditions in case, it thinks the "Menu3-Menu4" same as "Menu1-Menu2"